# Vector values manipulation in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am working on image processing and I need some help regarding storage and manuplitaion of images.

I have 40 frames to which I have varied the threshold `(0 to 255)`. And these images are stored in a `vector`. Now I have something like an array of values in which values of all the different frame are stored. I want add up individual frames which has the same threshold value and get an average of it.

For instance the `vector` will contain values such as `F0(0), F0(1),...,F0(254), F1(0),F1(1),....,F1(254).....,F39(0),F39(1),.....,F39(254)`. Here the `F0,F1,..,F39` are the frames and the numbers inside the small brackets represent the threshold  value.

I want to add up `F0(0)+F1(0)+..+F39(0)/49`, `F0(1)+F1(1)+..+F39(1)/49` till `F0(254)+F1(254)+..+F39(254)/49`.
I am searching for way to extract the stored vectors and do the manuplation.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Overload your `operator+` ??

Comment: Have a look at the much-neglected `std::valarray` container.

Comment: I am using 'vector< boost::array<float, 255> > vec;' and through 'tp_list.push_back(va);'Now I want to acces these values and do the caluclation as I mentioned before.